# How to remove this gear knob?

Tags: gear-stick

I’m trying to remove a damp carpet and this gear knob needs to be removed first.  At first I tried to turn anti clockwise but it was just way too strong.  I then used a spanner just underneath the knon(you can see the nut looking thing).  This was really strong but it did work a bit and seemed to move the gear knob up.  I know it’s working via a little space seems to be created under the knob and the gear locations diagram is now at an angle.

However the knob is no longer turning and the spanner doesn’t seem to be hooking tightly it just turns without turning the knob.  It feels as though thevspanner scrapped metal if he surface of the nut and you can see in the picture the metal under the gear knob is detetiorating.

Anyway how can I get it off and it seems I’ve f d it up?  Why did the spanner carve the metal off?

Anyway what can I do to salvage the situation?  I need to move this ASAP as damp situation is getting worse.  Please help![image][image]

Comment: Make, Model, and Year of Vehicle?

Comment: honda civic vti coupe 1999.  However the gear stick is not stock, it is taken from a honda civic type r 98-2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which way did you try to turn the nut? I don't know what car this is so it's a bit of a wild guess, but I'm inclined to say that the nut is a **locking nut/jam nut**. Meaning that you are supposed to **turn it clockwise** (when looking at it from above) in order to loosen the gear knob. The point of the jam nut is to load up the threads under the gear knob to make sure it doesn't move (so that the shift pattern doesn't rotate while you're driving). Which means that if you've been turning it counter-clockwise, you've just tightened the gear knob even more.

If you've rounded the nut to the point where your spanner slips, then you'll have to use a vice grips. Hold the nut tightly with the vice grips, hold the gear knob with your other hand, and then try to turn the nut clockwise. Eventually it should loosen and then it should be easy to remove the gear knob by turning it counter-clockwise. You can then replace the locking nut with a new one.

Comment: If you inspect the nut really closely and determine that it's actually the same piece as the gear knob, then that means it's not a locking nut and my answer won't help you. That being said, I'm not aware of gear knobs that have a nut-portion on them like this (what kind of design uses this?). And considering your situation, you can't really mess it up even more, so I think it's worth trying.

Comment: Some have a friction ring  - equivalent to a nyloc nut that holds the knob in position... but should not be that tight anyway...

Comment: @Kitsunemimi I think this is the knob:  https://www.icbmotorsport.com/usjdmektyrti.html  .  Does that help?  The black but maybe for the bottom of the stick.

Comment: @Kitsunemimi as I turned it anti-clockwise you could see the knob.  Was going up evidenced by the black box beneath it.  Does that mean it was coming off and I was right to go anti clockwise?

Comment: @JamesWilson If you turn it counter clockwise, it can make the shift knob turn counter clockwise a bit too, but eventually it would lock up and become very difficult to continue turning that way.

Comment: If your shift knob is the same as the one you linked, then that's definitely a locking nut and you should definitely turn the nut clockwise in order to loosen the shift knob itself.

Answer (score 3):

Some gear knobs are threaded, some are a friction fit, others are pinned.

If it is pinned you may well have "hidden" the pin with the damage you have done...

Threaded ones can be **very** tight - depends how strong you are, friction fits can also be tight but I have always managed to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Until the knob is released you can manage the wet carpet. Get a good, strong wet-dry vacuum cleaner and remove as much water as you can. Then use a sponge to saturate the carpet with (a warm water/drops of detergent/drops of bleach) solution. Then vacuum it all up and repeat several times. The idea is to get a few drops of bleach and detergent throughout the damp carpet, to hopefully delay any bad smell uhtil you can lift the carpet.

Comment: should i just get any cheap wet dry vac like this https://www.screwfix.eu/rac-wet-dry-car-vacuum-cleaner-12v.html or might it not be up to the job?  thanks.

Comment: Try to borrow a big shop-vac. Be sure to remove any paper filter inside the vac before attacking the wet stuff.