# Rounded gear knob, do I need to replace locking nut?

Tags: gear-stick

[image]Previously asked this:  [How to remove this gear knob?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/72447/how-to-remove-this-gear-knob)

Best answer was right about method to remove gear knob.  However in the end I managed to remove carpet without removing gear knob so there was no need to remove it further.

However the knob has been rounded and it is currently way above.  Can I use a vice grip and just turn it clockwise back into place.  The answer might be obviously yes however the answer in the other question said I can put a new locking nut but I'm wondering why this is needed?  Can I not just use a vice grip and clockwise it back into place?

Also does the fact that the knob currently being raised have any affect on transmission i.e. has anything underneath been mechanically moved?  I was hoping to drive it until I get a vice grip to fix this.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're meaning by "currently way above".  Perhaps a photo would help to explain your situation.

Comment: @jwh20 I've added a pic.  you can see I have rounded the bottom of the knob and created a gap(i have drawn a red arrow in pic) which has created as a result of me forcing the knob anti clockwise(should have been clockwise then anti clockwise).  This gap is what I meant by way above.  there should be no gap. Why cant I just use a vice grip and clockwise it back into place?

Answer (score 1):

Undo the locknut, move the locknut down and then easily turn the gear knob to the correct height. Then use the locknut to secure the knob position.

You can use the correct sized spanner for the locknut and you should not need a visegrip on the knob. Unless you are trying to force the knob and locknut to turn at the same time - this may well damage something, so don't.

Comment: Spot on and is the best advice I could give as well.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand this answer.  please see pic.  the lock nut is the part that I have rounded right?  How can I turn this without a vice grip since its been rounded.

Comment: The highlighted gap was created by me forcing the lock nut anti clockwise with the knob on top i.e both at the same time..  Does this mean i already damaged something? Since I already forced both up at the same time, cant I just turn the locknut(which would do the gear knob aswell) to go down at the same time?

Comment: Undo the locknut so it does not lock the knob any more...

Comment: By this you mean hold the gear knob, use a vice grip and turn the lock nut clockwise to take it back down, and then turn the knob clockwise to take it down and adjust as needed?